# powershell regexp to replace *[ ('any character' 'left bracket'] and replace with *`n[ ('any character' 'new line' 'left bracket')

Tags: regex, powershell

I have this script that works rather well.

```
$files = @(get-childitem -include *.txt -recurse -path $path -filter $filter)
Write-Host "files loaded";
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $out1Pass = "$file" + ".1pass"
    $outFile = "$file" + "2"

    Get-Content $file | Foreach-object {
        $_ -replace "`t","" `
        -replace '\]\[',"]`r`n["
    } | Set-Content $outFile 
}
```

but it would work even better if instead of 
    -replace '][',"]`r`n["

I could do something like
    -replace '*[',"*`r`n["

`and
    -replace '\]\*',"]`r`n*"

if * representing any character.

but... alas, such a format doesn't work.

Sample of input vs output

input:

```
reaction_other

[OBJECT:REACTION]

[REACTION:TAN_A_HIDE]
    [NAME:tan a hide]
    [BUILDING:TANNER:CUSTOM_T]
    [REAGENT:A:1:NONE:NONE:NONE:NONE][USE_BODY_COMPONENT][UNROTTEN]
        [HAS_MATERIAL_REACTION_PRODUCT:TAN_MAT]
```

output:

```
reaction_other

[OBJECT:REACTION]

[REACTION:TAN_A_HIDE]
[NAME:tan a hide]
[BUILDING:TANNER:CUSTOM_T]
[REAGENT:A:1:NONE:NONE:NONE:NONE]
[USE_BODY_COMPONENT]
[UNROTTEN]
[HAS_MATERIAL_REACTION_PRODUCT:TAN_MAT]
```

**Update**
Okay, I tried your script.  It works better than what I originally had.  However, there is one more minor caveat.

Here's sample data showing the issue:

Input:

```
item_gloves

[OBJECT:ITEM]

###test###[ITEM_GLOVES:ITEM_GLOVES_GAUNTLETS][NAME:gauntlet:gauntlets]###TEST[ARMORLEVEL:2]
[UPSTEP:1]
[SHAPED]
[LAYER:ARMOR]
[COVERAGE:100]
[LAYER_SIZE:20]
[LAYER_PERMIT:15]
[MATERIAL_SIZE:2]
[SCALED]
[BARRED]
[METAL]
[LEATHER]
[HARD]
```

Output:

```
item_gloves

[OBJECT:ITEM]

###test###[ITEM_GLOVES:ITEM_GLOVES_GAUNTLETS]
[NAME:gauntlet:gauntlets]###TEST
[ARMORLEVEL:2]
[UPSTEP:1]
[SHAPED]
[LAYER:ARMOR]
[COVERAGE:100]
[LAYER_SIZE:20]
[LAYER_PERMIT:15]
[MATERIAL_SIZE:2]
[SCALED]
[BARRED]
[METAL]
[LEATHER]
[HARD]
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include the text you want to match, and desired result.

Comment: So, is it safe to say that what you want is each `[whatever]` block to be on its own line?

Comment: yes.  I also wanted to replace *[ 'any character''left bracket' with *`n[ 'any character''new line''left bracket' and ]* 'right bracket''any character' with ]*`n 'right bracket''new line'.  thank you btw

Comment: I guess I'm still a bit confused about the goal here. Your original script works well. Why do you want to change it? Are you trying to replace your 2 `-replace` operations with a single `-replace`?

Comment: sometimes I have items in the file that are not in brackets.  Hence why I'm looking for * replacements.  Say I have a line: [USE_BODY_COMPONENT]###Comment... it won't split the ###Comment off onto it's own line.

Comment: I see, please edit your sample input text to reflect that, and I think from there I can edit my answer to work with that scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```powershell
$inputText = @"
reaction_other

[OBJECT:REACTION]

[REACTION:TAN_A_HIDE]
    [NAME:tan a hide]
    [BUILDING:TANNER:CUSTOM_T] ## Some comment here
    [REAGENT:A:1:NONE:NONE:NONE:NONE] # Here [USE_BODY_COMPONENT] ## Inline comment [UNROTTEN]
        [HAS_MATERIAL_REACTION_PRODUCT:TAN_MAT]
"@

$outputText = $inputText -replace '(?m)^\s*','' `
              -replace '(\[.+?\][^\[\r\n]*)(?=\[)' , "`$1`r`n"
```

### How This Works

It's still being done in 2 `-replace`s.

#### Replace 1:

The first `-replace` removes all of the leading whitespace:

1. `(?m)` is the inline regex mode specifier where `m` stands for "multiline" and it effectively makes `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of *each line* rather than the beginning and end of the whole string.
2. `^` is therefore matching the beginning of each line.
3. `\s` is a character class that stands for most whitespace, including spaces and tabs.
4. `*` means zero or more.

So effectively this says:

> Replace all whitespace at the beginning of each line with an empty string (effectively removing it).

#### Replace 2:

1. We start by opening a capturing group with `(`.
2. Next we match a literal left bracket with `\[`, followed by 1 or more of any character (non-greedy), followed by a literal right bracket `\]`.
3. Still in our capturing group, we start a character class by using `[` (not escaped), and in this context `^` means `NOT`, so whatever we put inside the class must not be present.
4. Inside the character class, we use a literal left bracket `\[`, a CR `\r` and a LF `\n`, then close the class `]`. We use `*` to indicate that we want 0 or more of that class.
5. The capturing group is now closed.
6. This next part is a positive lookahead. It looks to see if there is a particular match coming up, **but the critical part here is that it does not consume those characters**, therefore they are not part of the match, therefore they will not be replaced.
7. The replacement string is the value of the first capture group, followed by CRLF. Note the double quoted string. This requires us to escape the `$` using backtick, so that powershell doesn't interpret `$1` as a powershell variable. Instead a literal `$1` string will be sent to the regex engine, where it will interpret as a backreference.

So this replace is basically saying:

> Find a string inside of square brackets `[*]` optionally followed by any amount of text that is not a `[` or a line ending. But, *only count it as a match if there is a `[` directly following the matched string*.
>   If all conditions are met, replace that string with itself followed by CRLF.

Comment: I tried replacing the part of my formula with yours and nogo $files = @(get-childitem -include *.txt -recurse -path $path -filter $filter)
Write-Host "files loaded";
foreach ($file in $files) {
        $out1Pass = "$file" + ".1pass"
  $outFile = "$file" + "2"

        Get-Content $file | Foreach-object {
            $_ -replace "`t","" `
   -replace '(.)\[' , '$1\r\n\['
   
        } | Set-Content $outFile 
    } 
 I got this '[REAGENT:A:1:NONE:NONE:NONE:NONE]\r\n\[USE_BODY_COMPONENT]\r\n\[UNROTTEN]' vs '[REAGENT:A:1:NONE:NONE:NONE:NONE]
[USE_BODY_COMPONENT]
[UNROTTEN]'

Comment: yeah, it would be best if you could implement your suggestion into the following script.

Comment: I also tried...$files = @(get-childitem -include *.txt -recurse -path $path -filter $filter)
Write-Host "files loaded";
foreach ($file in $files) {
        $out1Pass = "$file" + ".1pass"
  $outFile = "$file" + "2"

        Get-Content $file | Foreach-object {
            $_ -replace "`t","" `
   -replace '(.)\[' , '$1\r\n\['
   $text = 'x[something'
   $newText = $text -replace '(.)\[' , '$1\r\n\['
   
        } | Set-Content $outFile 
    } 
  nogo

Comment: um... I batch operate this on a ton of *.txt files, not just one file... so I don't know if your $inputText = @ is going to work.  How would I apply this to the original script and not just a script hard modeled on specific input.

Comment: The code in my answer merely demonstrates the usage of those expressions. The `$inputText` variable would be replaced by `$_` in your original script, and you would leave out `$outputText`.

Comment: thank you very much, i'm still reading your elegant solution and how it goes above and beyond what I asked for.

Comment: Quick Question.  Given the example above, if comments are before any [, does it address that as well.  I read what you said about ?m, but that's about whitespace.  Say I had a ###Comment[token]  Does it also check data BEFORE any [token] is found?

Comment: I'm thinking I need to do a negative lookahead?  I see you did the hard work of matching data within brackets... Next we match a literal left bracket with \[, followed by 1 or more of any character (non-greedy), followed by a literal right bracket \]... Problem with this approach is if there are broken brackets in my file, then it needs to not read the rest of what it started with the last left bracket and resume any new left bracket.